# C#, Unity: How Can I use different class objects for the same constructor?

Tags: c#, class, constructor, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a simple game in unity and would like to construct a combat function

`public CombatVsMonster (Character character, Monster monster)`

this is what I have (takes a character and monster and executes a combat)

How can I make the same code work with (merging those two, so the second constructor can be either Monster or Character class)

```
public CombatVsMonster (Character character, Character character)
```

in other words: Can I have a constructor that would be able to take in different class objects? If yes: how?

Comment: Does `Monster` derive from `Character`?

Comment: No, but has similar characteristics. Would deriving help?

Comment: There are many possible approaches to what you're describing.  When you make a complete attempt, is there a specific error or problem that you encounter?

Comment: @David my attempt was to use void, but that got an error messege

Comment: @Bronsoner: "Use void" how?  These look like constructors, and constructors don't have return types, void or otherwise.  What was the attempt and what was the error?

Comment: Yes. Use interfaces.

Comment: @David I'm not sure what your asking of me, I'm trying to solve a problem while wrting the code

Comment: @Brandon - could you be more specific?

Comment: You can "use interfaces", or "use inheritance", or probably "use generics", or "use multiple constructors", or even change the design of the entire thing in some fundamental way.  So far the question is a bit broad and unclear to me.  If you have specific code which produces a specific error, we can probably help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this, but a common thread shared by most games which include any sort of "`Monster`" is that the player, monsters, etc all have some things in common, such as HitPoints.

If that's true of yours as well, then using [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) is probably the easiest way to accomplish what you want.   "`Character`" should have things common to all `Character`s, be them NPCs or the player.   From there, if `Player` and `Monster` both inherit from `Character`, then you can pass them both to any function that accepts `Character` as a parameter.  This should save you a lot of code, since it would allow one function to handle interactions between `Character`s.  They will both have all of the features of a `Character`, but will also have their own attributes and properties.

Comment: This makes it clear to me: I'll make a new Class and derive both Character and Monster from it. Your solution was clear and through.Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Don't forget to set your question as Answered!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an interface that will be inherited to its childs.

```
class Character : MonoBehavior, IActor
{
     public float Hp {get;set;}

     private float _damage;
     public float Damage
     {
          get {return _damage;}
          set {_damage = value;}
     }
     //implemetation of IActor
}

class Monster : MonoBehavior, IActor
{
    //implemetation of IActor
}

interface IActor
{
    float Hp {get;set;}
    float Damage {get;set;}
}

public Combat (IActor character, IActor character2)
```

Comment: I already figured it out thanks to user1895086, but your solution works too. Thank you.